# How to create ionic-v1 login

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mobile, ionic-v1

I'm new in ionic framework. I'm trying to create login with mysql database, but don't know how to do it.

controller:

```js
app.controller('loginuserCtrl', function($scope, UserService, $state) {
    $scope.user = {};
 
    $scope.login = function() {
        UserService.getLogin($scope.user.username,$scope.user.password).success(function(response) {
            $state.go('profile');
        
            var data = response.data;

            switch (data.code) {
                case '00':
                    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
                    break;
                case '99':
                    break;
            }
        }) 
    };
});
```

```html
<ion-view view-title="Login" name="loginUser">
  <ion-content class="padding">
     
      <div class="list list-inset">
          <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="user.username">
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password">
          </label>
      </div>
      <button class="button button-block button-calm" ng-click="login()">Login</button>
      
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

service.js:

```js
var app = angular.module('services', []);

app.service('UserService', function ($http, config) {
    return {
        getLogin: function (saveObj) {
            return $http.get(config.serverIp + 'Login',saveObj);
        }
      };
});
```

server.js

```js
//select user login
app.get('/Login', function (req, res) {
    var query = req.query;

var sql = "SELECT * FROM sys_user WHERE usr_id = '" + query.usr_id + "'and usr_identno = '" + query.usr_identno + "'";

    connection.query(sql, function (err, rows, field) {
        if (!err) {
            res.json({code: '00', content: rows});
        } else {
            throw err;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Where is the problem ? Send us your error trace

Comment: my login page not working, there are no error I just dont know how to make my login page working. For example, without username or password still can go to the next page, no execution. Please guide me, I'm new in ionic framework. Thank you.